# please check my code on updating child component from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
     input: '',
  }
  this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
 }

 handler(input) {
   this.setState({
     input: input
   })
 }

 render() {
   return <Child1 handler = {this.handler} />
 }
}

class Child1 extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (<div> this.props.handler("hey") </div>);
   }
}
```

Also, if there is Child2 that is a child of the parent class above,

so:

```
Parent
  -Child
  -Child2
```

How would I implement it so that I can pass "hey" down to Child2?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure I am following you correctly,
You have Parent component with 2 child components
and you want to pass the "hey" from one child to another, am I correct?

So basically what you did should be fine, the parent got the hey param and set it in the state, all you have to do now is to give Child2 the input as a property

Which should look like this:

```
<Child2 handler = {this.handler} input={this.state.input}/>
```

Then you can access the input in child2 by referring to:

`this.props.input`